# Как перенести случайные элементы из одного массива в другие?

Tags: c#, массивы

Делаю небольшую игру на Unity, есть 3 массива:

```
string[] ItemsList = new string[10] //список всех элементов, из которого и надо выбрать случайные
{
     "item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5", "item6", "item7", "item8", "item9", "item10"
};

string[] FirstPlayersItems = new string[5] // надо заполнить элементами из ItemsList
{
    "","","","",""
};

string[] SecondPlayersItems = new string[5] //надо заполнить элементами из ItemsList
{
    "","","","",""
};
```

Как прописать наполнение FirstPlayersItems и SecondPlayersItems случайными элементами из ItemsList?
Элементы могут повторяться.
Поиск в интернете ничего не дал, все похожие вопросы были про числовые массивы (int), а там команды другие.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю как-то так:

```
foreach(var item in FirstPlayersItems)
{
    item = ItemsList[UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, ItemsList.Length);
}
foreach(var item in SecondPlayersItems)
{
    item = ItemsList[UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, ItemsList.Length);
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо за ваш ответ. Он натолкнул меня на идею перебора всего ItemsList в одну переменную, которая становится элементом PlayersItems. 
в итоге у меня получилось вот так:
 private string Container;

 for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
 {
 Container = ItemsList[UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 9)];
 FirstPlayersItems[i] = Container;
 }
 
 Я решил проверить как код работает, и прописал вывод FirstPlayersItems в консоль:
 for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
 {Debug.Log(i + "й элемент =" + FirstPlayersItems[i]);}
 
 Потом я заполнил FirstPlayersItems от 1 до 10, и получил 9,3,4,9 и 5

Comment: Прошу прощения за скомканность - слишком маленькое ограничение по символам, пришлось экономить каждый пробел